# Java socket not closing

Tags: java, sockets

Okay... I'm new to java and this is my first application. I'm putting together a java sockets application. When connected, it changes the button label from "Connect" to "Disconnect". If button label = disconnect, then socket.close. Not sure why it's not closing. Is it because it's private? I'm aware there are probably better ways of determining if the socket is open, etc. BUT I'm really first, trying to understand why the following isn't working. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks!

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    Socket s = new Socket();
    String host = jTextField1.getText();
    double d = Double.parseDouble(jTextField2.getText());
    int port = (int) d;
    if (jLabel4.getText() == "Disconnected") {
        try {
            s.connect(new InetSocketAddress(host, port), 60);
            jLabel4.setText("Connected");
            jButton1.setText("Disconnect");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SARP_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    } else {
        try {
            s.close();
            jLabel4.setText("Disconnected");
            jButton1.setText("Connect");
        } catch (IOException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(SARP_UI.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
```

Comment: You should not compare strings with ==

Comment: Beside that, what are the symptoms? Does your program log anything? Crashes?

Answer (score 2):

I can't understand how your program is supposed to work. The socket `s` is local to the action handler, so either you connect a newly allocated socket, or you close a never used one. I think you should revisit your program and keep the socket as a field of some object, so you could query its [state](http://www.tcpipguide.com/free/t_TCPOperationalOverviewandtheTCPFiniteStateMachineF-2.htm) and operate accordingly to the current state of the program and the user requests coming from the GUI.

Also, note that strings should be compared with `Object.equals()`, not with `==`, because `==` checks object identity and is unreliable for runtime checks (even if sometimes it works when arguments are compile-time constants or interned strings).

Also, your program should keep an internal boolean flag instead of checking the value of a label (for example, what if this were a real app and you added a translation?)

Answer (score 0):

It is probably because of `String` comparison.
Try

```
if(jLabel4.getText().equals("Disconnected"))
```

if this does not solve your problem, keep a `boolean` which indicates connected or not, instead of reading the string from the label.

Such as

```
boolean connected;
\\ something
if(connected)
\\ do this
else
\\do that
```

**Edit:** Also, you should make socket out of the class scope. It must be a class member.